# VAE Decoder returns a different type of data (Bool vs Float - Keras)

Tags: keras, types, autoencoder

I’m trying to generate some data from my VAE Decoder but I don’t understand why it’s output data type are different from the input.  
My dataset is based of booleans arrays. Some are organized and others don’t. Here’s an example:

```
1010101010101010
1000100010001000
1000000010000000
```

Is an organized array with repetition

```
1001110011101010
0110011011001000
0001111010100110
```

Is a randomly generated array

I’ve trained the model on 10 000 examples, both organized and randoms. 
The results seems corrects as we can see in this graph of the latent space :

[Representation of the latent space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2tzY.png)

Blue dots are the randoms arrays and yellow are the organized ones.  
Given this, I’d like to generate a new array from coordinates thanks to the decoder.

My model is the variational auto encoder from Keras :

https://keras.io/examples/variational_autoencoder/

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py

My code is available at :
https://github.com/KyrillosL/SimpleVAEMidi/blob/master/unquantized_v2_temperature_algo_gen/vae_evaluator.py

I generate my array from the decoder with :

```
z_sample = np.array([(0,0),(0,1)]) 
x_decoded = self.decoder.predict(z_sample)
print(x_decoded)
```

I used (0,0) as coord from the latent space and (0,1) for the mean and std as the documentation says :
The decoder can be used to generate MNIST digits by sampling the latent vector from a Gaussian distribution with mean = 0 and std = 1.

I thought the schema would be : [AE Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkWV5.png)

But unfortunately it the x_decoded returns me a 2 dimensional array  with values going from ~0 to ~0.4 :

```
[[0.07802552 0.07745907 0.07709804 ... 0.2573312  0.25953    0.25999647]
 [0.04232737 0.04368901 0.04162821 ... 0.3448236  0.3477785  0.34735686]]
```

I tried to convert them to a boolean array but it just cut the array at the middle like this :

```
[[True True True ... False  False  False]
 [True True True ... False  False  False]]
```

I’d like know what I did wrong and how to decode my latent space in order to generate a new array of booleans.

Thanks !